# Find the area bounded by the hypercycloid

Tags: definite-integrals, intuition, vector-analysis

Parametrization : $x = acos^3(t), y = asin^3(t)$
$a>0$

If you can solve it for me that would be awesome.:D If not, can you give me some hints? Tell me how  to set it up and stuff. It's solveable by green's theorem allegedly. But I'm utterly lost. I still have a hard time understanding green's theorem and how the problems are set up.I mean I understand that you take the parital of the first function minus the second function partial, but usually I don't understand where they pull the vector fields from to apply to a problem like this that doesn't have a vector field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugging the vector field $\vec{F}(x,y)=y\vec{i}+-x\vec{j}$ into Green's Theorem, we achieve $\int_\vec{X}(y\vec{i}+-x\vec{j})d\vec{s}=\int\int_D 2 dx dy$. Therefore, the area of the region is $\frac{1}{2}\int_\vec{X}(y\vec{i}+-x\vec{j})d\vec{s}$. The reason that one chooses the vector field such is that this particular vector field makes the line integral become an area. Most vector fields do not have this property. And choosing a vector field out of thin air is one of those things, like treating derivatives as fractions, that make mathematicians uncomfortable but work anyways.

Comment: That right there! That is always what confuses me. You are pulling a vector field out of thin air. How do you choose the vector field. Why does it work? Do you have a video or something that explains this in laymen's terms for a noob like me?

Comment: The vector field is $\vec{F}(x,y)=y\vec{i}+x\vec{j}$ is conservative and hence its line integral is zero. I believe you intended to have a negative sign in there: $\vec{F}(x,y)=-y\vec{i}+x\vec{j}$.

Comment: And what is $\vec{x}$?

Comment: @DavidH Thanks, now corrected.

Comment: @user121615 Where?

Comment: It looks like your notation says take the integral along some vector x. Am I misreading?

Comment: @user121615 Yes, you are misreading. The arrow isn't over the $x$, it's over the $j$.

Comment: There is an arrow directly over an x riiiight in front of the integral. It's the very first thing after the integral and it looks like it's the bottom limit of integration.

Comment: @user121615 Yes, this is standard notation for a line integral and is the path $\vec{X}$ over which the line integral is taken.